# Sublime Text 2 build path errors

Tags: python, build, path, sublimetext2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my build configuration so that cmd points to actual location of the python interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030746/how-do-i-change-my-build-configuration-so-that-cmd-points-to-actual-location-of)

I just got Sublime Text 2 and I love it. When I try to run Python in it, I get an error:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'python', u'-u', u'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\RandomStuff\\python\\rpg\\Characters.py']]
[dir:  C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\RandomStuff\python\rpg]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin]
[Finished]
```

Comment: Change build configuration so that `cmd` points to actual location of python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `python` on your command line...